# how to connect two docker container with host UDP port

Tags: docker

I am running the two containers. Both containers want to listen the host machine's UDP port. I am getting the data from host over UDP port 1234 and I want to run two containers which will listen the host over UDP port. I think two processes can listen the same UDP port.

I have created two container ffmpeg1 and ffmpeg2.

running first:

```
docker run --rm -p 1234:1234/udp -it ffmpeg
docker run --rm -p 1234:5000/udp -it ffmpeg2
```

getting the below error when tried to run second container.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint reverent_germain (9915c14466f78f3ae2215d9e53edc502a9b6fff81f08f05f52d79088): Bind for 0.0.0.0:1234 failed: port is already allocated.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the ports because first port defines your local interface and the second one defines your container port.

```
docker run --rm -p 1234:1234/udp -it ffmpeg
docker run --rm -p 5000:1234/udp -it ffmpeg2
```

Comment: I am receiving the data at port 1234 in host machine. if i tried to listen to 5000 the I will not receive ant data.

Comment: You **cannot** listen the *same port* in the same network; however, you can use load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not listen the same UDP port on one host.
So in second container, let use another port, eg: 1235

```
docker run --rm -p 1235:5000/udp -it ffmpeg2
```

Or in one host. You can call directly from container by creating network
1) Create new network:

`$ docker network create ffmpeg`

2) Connect containers to network

```
$ docker run --rm --name=ffmpeg --net=ffmpeg -it ffmpeg
$ docker run --rm --name=ffmpeg2 --net=ffmpeg -it ffmpeg
```

3) Now you can call directly from container by container name ffmpeg, ffmpeg2

Comment: FFMpeg uses UDP 1234 as a default port, so I think that the guy was trying to use different port, but also, doesn't want to change the default UDP port value

Comment: if I used the different host port as you said 1235 then how i will get the data which is present at host port 1234.

Comment: if you choose port 1235 you can use this port to get the data

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to different IPs on host machine, if multiple network cards are available on your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

1) if the data is broadcasting UDP, binds to different ip:same_port, you can sign different ip to the same network card.
2) use a port duplicating method on host, i.e., port 1234 -> 1235